# ms access how running subtraction instead of running addition

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a query using a calculation. What I'm trying to accomplish is making a query to create a running subtraction instead of addition.

I've tried a few different ways but always seem to end with either an error or with no results showing.
Any and all help would be appreciated thank you.

This is the query:

[image: query]

I want to do running subtraction not running addition, but I can't find any function that will subtract the number.

[image: function]

[this is the result that im trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qE0s.png)

Comment: Please add sample data with expected results. A running substraction usually is just the negative of a running addition, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Please do not post code in pictures, rather include the query you came up with in your question.

Comment: SELECT ledger.ID, ledger.[Expense:(type)], ledger.[Fund allotment],ledger.Amount, DSum("[amount]","[ledger]","[ID] <=" & [ID]) AS BALANCE
FROM ledger;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

```
SELECT 
    ledger.ID, 
    ledger.[Expense:(type)], 
    ledger.[Fund allotment],
    ledger.Amount,  
        (Select Amount From ledger 
        Where ledger.ID = (Select Min(ID) From Ledger))-
        Nz((Select Sum(T.Amount) From ledger As T 
        Where T.ID > (Select Min(ID) From Ledger) And T.ID <= ledger.ID), 0) As 
    Balance
FROM
    ledger
```